# I don't know how to replace config.properties by test properties Spring / JUnit

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, junit4, spring-config

The thing is that have a project that uses a configuration class to get all the config properties

```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("file:/external/path/config/config.properties")
   public class AppSettings {
        @Value("${SOME.PROPERTY}")
        public String SOME_PROPERTY;
   }
```

So in my test configuration class I just replace the properties using this:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:testconfig.properties")
```

So it's work (in my local), it replace the config by the testconfig.
But when i deploy it in the certification environment it throws `FileNotFoundException: /external/path/config/config.properties`  this config.properties is in an external path, so the deploy can not access to that path.

that testconfig.properties is inside the project so I need to read this instead of the config.properties  ...but is still reading it and throwing error.

How can i replace the config.properties  properly when I run test?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dot after `:`

`@PropertySource("file:./server/path/config/config.properties")`

Also take a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) chapter of spring documentation, it might be useful for you.

Comment: thanks but the path is good. What i'm trying to say is that i don't want to read that path when I run the test. because in that environment who deploy the app can not access to external paths.